# How can I find the domain of this function?

Tags: calculus

$f(x)=\sqrt{9-x^2}$
To get the domain
I did these steps

$1)\; 9-x^2≥0$

$2)\; -x^2≥-9$

$3)\; x^2 ≤ 9$

$4)\; x  ≤ 3$ or $-3$

that means $x≤3$ and $x≤-3$
but why after long search on internet the steps were like this?

$1)\; 9-x^2≥ 0$

$2)\; -x^2≥-9$

$3)\; x^2 ≤ 9$

$4)\; |x| ≤ 3$

why we should use absolute value here?
Is not it supposed to be $x ≤ +3$ or $-3$ ?
And how to conclude from that the domain of the function?

Comment: $x\le -3$ is certainly not correct. Take, say, $x=-4$. Is $x^2<9$ then true?

Comment: Please see [How can I format mathematics here?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) in our [Help center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help), as well as further links given there.

Comment: PS. I made some basic fixex, please do the rest.

Comment: Your mistake is that your line 4 does *not* follow from your line 3. Inequalities aren't equations.

Comment: The absolute value arises since $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$.  For instance, $\sqrt{(-1)^2} = \sqrt{1} = 1$ since the symbol $\sqrt{x}$ represents the principal (nonnegative) square root of a number $x$, if it exists.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution for the domain**

> We demand that $\ 9-x^2 \ge0 \Rightarrow 9\ge x^2 \Rightarrow \vert x \vert \le3$
> $\text{So the domain for this fuction is:} D=[-3,3]$

---

**Why we follow this method?**

> $\text{As has been already mentioned in the comments there is a diffrence between equalities}$
> $\text{and inequalities.Let's see an example:}$
> $x=2 \Rightarrow x^2=4 \text{ but } x^2=4\Rightarrow x=2 \text{ it's not always true because:}
> $ $x= -2$ $\Rightarrow$ $x^2=4 $
> $\text{Let's see another example with inequalities:}$
> $-2<1\Rightarrow4<1$
> $\text{As you can see there is a fatal error when i am trying to raise to power of 2}$
> $\text{(and general in eveen powers) because 4 is not bigger than 1}$
> $\text{That's why we use the absolute value.Lets use it to correct my first mistake:}$
> $x^2=4 \Rightarrow \vert x\vert=2 \Rightarrow x=\pm2$
> $\text{By using the absolute value we are sure that we get all the possible solutions.}$
> $\text{The second error that i made was to show you that some properties that are valid to}$
> $\text{equalities are not in inequaliities.}$
> $\text{Also by using symbols like "$\Rightarrow$" its clear that we can only move to}$
> $\text{one direction and not the opposite}$

Comment: only to make sure of my understanding we are compelled to the principle square root to ensure the signs are mathematically correct in inequalities for example 4>1                                 when we take the square root it will be + or -2 if -2>1 that is not correct so we should take principle  to be 2>1

Comment: I used this example to ilustrate that its **dangerous** to raise in even powers in equalities.It is allowed when both sides are **positive**.In my example(4>1) you can't go "backwards".It can be also 2>1 or 2>-1.You don't know.What's why **we dont raise inequalities in even powers if both sides are not positive**.Feel free to ask anything you want about this

Comment: @  Constantinos Pisimisis                                                                                                                 

For this inequality : x^2>4 to solve it: |x|>2 instead of square root for both sides x>+-2 to ensure to avoid making flaw in our inequality because if we do it will x>2 or 2<-2 is that right

Comment: @yh_2004 **You can't use the principle square root in inequalities**That's why we use the absolute value

Answer (score 1):

To find the domain of many of these simple equations it helps to understand when a function does not give a real solution. When does that happen? For instance, $1/x$ works for every $x\ne0$; $\sqrt x$ works for all $x \ge0$. Thus, from your problem, you can tell that if you subtract any number greater than $9$ from $9$, you'd get a negative number. Hence, $D:-3\le x \le 3$.

I think the main takeaway is that you need to understand what these equations mean. Blindly following algebra won't get you anywhere if you cannot make sense of what you're doing and WHY you're doing it.

Answer (score 0):

$9-x^2≥0$

$(3-x)(3+x)≥0$

Now, product of two terms is positive. It is possible if both terms are either positive or both negative.

**Case-1 : When both are positive**

$3-x≥0$ and $3+x≥0$

$x≥-3$ and $x≤3$

You should work out the other case by yourself.

Also, you need to be aware of what is
[Absolute Value Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value?wprov=sfla1) . Whether your input is positive or negative, it returns it's positive value.

$|x| = 3$  means that $ x = ± 3$

However, $|x|≤3$ does not mean that $x≤±3$. The reason is that ;as pointed out in comments, the methods of solving inequalities is not all same as those of equalities, because inequalities are not equalities.

Comment: only to make sure of my solution the other case                                                                             x+3≤0      3-x ≤0       x≤-3         -x≤-3                                                                                                                                                                                       x≤-3          x≥3       domain is (-∞,∞)

Comment: Note that in the answer I provided, I had written an  **and**  between the inequalities. The purpose of  **and**  is that the both inequalities must follow at the same time and thus you'll have to take the intersection instead of union of the solution set of each.